# how to connect my sql in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have already done the db configuration for my laravel project but it gives me an error saying that 
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users` where `user_name` = admin limit 1)

but i have already dfined my dbname and password what is showing above is incorrect.
here is my login controller

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Login;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
class LoginController extends Controller {
    public function login(){
        $uname = Input::get('username');
        $pwd = Input::get('password');
        if (Auth::attempt(array('user_name' => $uname, 'password' => $pwd))){
            return "success";
        }
        else {
            return "Wrong Credentials";
        }    
     }
}
```

here is my .env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:Zm3uZ82dtjozo68rs2cGAlXXmzj9EuueqCcKsC73VTo=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=''

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

my config/database.php is as follows

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

//        'sqlite' => [
//            'driver' => 'sqlite',
//            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
//            'prefix' => '',
//        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

//        'pgsql' => [
//            'driver' => 'pgsql',
//            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
//            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
//            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
//            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
//            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
//            'charset' => 'utf8',
//            'prefix' => '',
//            'schema' => 'public',
//            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
//        ],

//        'sqlsrv' => [
//            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
//            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
//            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
//            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
//            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
//            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
//            'charset' => 'utf8',
//            'prefix' => '',
//        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

Answer (score 0):

As your .env looks fine I assume you're using `php artisan serve` to place your website online for localhost testing.

If you made these changes whilst `serve` was running it will not register live side. Simply stop `artisan serve` running and then run it again and the changes will take effect.

Comment: yes it worked that issue is gone now it is showing as follows

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test1.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `users` where `user_name` = admin limit 1)

Comment: Therefore your query isn't working but the problem its self is fixed. Please attempt to fix this new problem yourself and create a new question if you become stuck.

Comment: @pdmproject You're most welcome. As a small tip if you have the migration and model in place try `php artisan migrate` ;-). If this answer has rectified your issue please mark it so that others with a similar problem will be able also to rectify their issue.